# Error: No matching function for call to 'fraction::add(fraction&, fraction&)'

Tags: c++, oop, object

```
[Error] no matching function for call to 'fraction::add(fraction&, fraction&)'
line 105 which is
f3.add( f1, f2);
```

This is the error message I'm receiving when I try and compile.

Instance:
I'm trying to create a class of 'fraction' which allows my instructor's pre-set int main() to execute from.  I've so far constructed a bare-bones class, and am trying to compile to see if it works.

```
  'My class:
class fraction
{
private:
long num, den; 
public:
void setNum(long i_num)
{
    num=i_num;
}
void setDen(long)
{
}
long getNum()
{
return num; 
}
long getDen()
{
return den;
}

fraction()
{
    num = 1;
    den = 1;
}
fraction(int n, int d)
{
    num = n;
    if (d==0) 
    {
        cout << "Cannot divide by zero" << endl;
        exit(0); // will terminate the program if division by 0 is attempted
    }
    else
        den = d;
}

fraction add(fraction otherFraction)
{
    int n = num*otherFraction.den+otherFraction.num*den;
    int d = den*otherFraction.den;
    return fraction(n/gcd(n,d),d/gcd(n,d));
}

fraction sub(fraction otherFraction)
{
    int n = num*otherFraction.den-otherFraction.num*den;
    int d = den*otherFraction.den;
    return fraction(n/gcd(n,d),d/gcd(n,d));
}

fraction mult(fraction otherFraction)
{
    int n = num*otherFraction.num;
    int d = den*otherFraction.den;
    return fraction(n/gcd(n,d),d/gcd(n,d));
}

fraction div(fraction otherFraction)
{
    int n = num*otherFraction.den;
    int d = den*otherFraction.num;
    return fraction(n/gcd(n,d),d/gcd(n,d));
}


int gcd(int n, int d)
{
    int remainder;
    while (d != 0)
    {
        remainder = n % d;
        n = d;
        d = remainder;
    }
    return n;
}
void print() // Display method
{
    if (den == 1) // e.g. fraction 2/1 will display simply as 2
        cout << num << endl;
    else
        cout << num << "/" << den << endl;
}
};'
```

My instructor's int main():

```
int main ( )
{ // define seven instances of the class fraction
fraction f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7;
//set values for the numerator and denominator to f1 and print 
//them
f1.setDen( 2L);
f1.setNum( 0L);
f1.print();

//set values for the numerator and denominator to f2 and print them
f2.setDen( 4L);
f2.setNum( 3L); 
f2.print();
f3.add( f1, f2);
f3.print();
f4.sub( f1, f2);
f4.print();
f5.mult( f1, f2);
f5.print();
f6.div( f1, f2);
f6.print();
f7.inc(f1);
f7.print(f1);
```

My instructor informed us not to edit main() in any way.

I've traced it back to the method in the class

```
    fraction add(fraction otherFraction)
{
    int n = num*otherFraction.den+otherFraction.num*den;
    int d = den*otherFraction.den;
    return fraction(n/gcd(n,d),d/gcd(n,d));
}
```

How do I go about passing the variables in main() so they'll work in the class?
I've only been taught one way of doing things, and this is my first Object Oriented class.  He's teaching different ways of organizing and I'm not understanding it.  He's yet to e-mail me back with help *about a week now* (online class).

Any hints/tips would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Add a function declaration `fraction add(const fraction&, const fraction&)` to your class declaration file, and add an implementation for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you can see from the error reported, the compiler looks for a method with the following signature:

```
fraction::add(fraction&, fraction&)
```

while the method that you have defined have the following one:

```
fraction::add(fraction&)
```

so, you are missing an argument (another fraction).
I'm not quite sure about the meaning of the 'add' method (the way your instructor calls it) but I think it's about assigning the result of the sum of the two fraction to the one on which you are calling the object, that is  f3 = f1 +f2. In that case you should implement you add like this:

```
void add(const fraction& a,const fraction& b)
{
    int n = a.getNum()*b.getDen()+b.getNum()*a.getDen();
    int d = a.getDen()*b.getDen();

    num = n/gcd(n,d);
    dem = d/gcd(n,d);
}
```

more or less..:)

PS: I added some 'const francion&' just as an optimization to avoid copying the arguments each time you call the function. It's not strictly necessary but it's a very good programming practice..;)

Comment: You were faster, have a +1 :-)

Comment: I appreciate the quick and accurate responses.  Your tips were extremely helpful in solving a slew of problems I was having.

I did however have to remove the 'const' from the arguments, it wouldn't allow me to have them for some reason.

Now I just have to get the 'print' function to work, and I'm golden.

Thanks so very much.

Comment: @TonisWhite The reason why it doesn't allow them is that your getter functions aren't marked `const` (but they should be: `long getNum() const { return num; }`. That signifies "this function cannot modify the object it's called on," and can thus be called on a `const` object (or object held through a `const &`) as well.

Comment: `const &` doesn't really gain you anything with small value types like this. It doesn't matter here because the functions are simple and inline, but elsewhere `const &` on small value types can be a pessimisation. In particular, it can force the compiler to emit unnecessary memory accesses to satisfy aliasing rules.

Comment: @StuartOlsen, yeah, you are right for the first part. But even if they don't get you anything, in this particular case, I tought i would have been useful to show to a beginner a good practice that is "good" in a vast majority of situations... But I miss the second one (concerning the pessimisation), can you expand it a little bit,please?

Comment: Consider `void map_multiply (fraction* begin, fraction* end, const fraction& q) { while (begin != end) *begin++ *= q; }`. The function will have to load through the referemce to `q` each iteration, in case it aliases an object between `begin` and `end`. If `q` is passed by value, that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the prototype of your function:

```
fraction add(fraction otherFraction)
```

with the way the `main` calls it:

```
f3.add( f1, f2);
```

Do you see the mismatch? Your function takes one parameter, but `main()` calls it with two arguments. You need to add an extra parameter to your function.

I believe the intended semantics for `f3.add(f1, f2)` is `f3 = f1 + f2`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I see now that my arguments were wrong and needed a second reference to the class instances.  Thank you Angew.

Answer (score -3):

`add()` is a member function that takes one `fraction` parameter. But since it's being called on an instance of `fraction`, you'll be adding two objects, `otherFraction` and `*this`. `*this` is the instance of the object on which `add()` is being called, and `otherFraction` is the argument passed to `add()`:

```
f1.add(f2);
^       ^
|       |
----    -------------
*this   otherFraction
```

All you need to do is assign the result to `f3`:

```
f3 = f1.add(f2);
```

Comment: -1, the OP clearly states they are not allowed to change the contents of `main()`.

Comment: I appreciate the help, and the information is taken and assimilated.  However, Angew is correct in that my Instructor strictly prohibits the alteration of his int main().